# UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict: conda 4.0.8* -> conda-env <2.5 -> python 2.7* - python 3.6*

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, graphlab

I am new to Python. I am trying to use Graphlab create launcher to import Graphlab libraries in my python notebook. I already have Anaconda installed on my MacBook Pro(OSX).

When I start to run Graphlab create launcher, I get following error,

---

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - conda 4.0.8* -> conda-env <2.5 -> python 2.7*
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

---

You can find the detail of the log at https://github.com/jaysara/Python-ML/blob/master/launcher-install-log.txt

Can anyone help, why am I getting this error ?

Comment: Trying to get some help, what could be causing this error for me

Answer (score 3):

You will have to first install latest update of anaconda and then install graphlab. The best way to use graphlab is using a `Virtual env` that I guess you are using. You may try in your terminal

```
conda update conda
```

To first get latest anaconda that may support graphlab. You may like to read the documentation on Graphlab how to create `virtual env` and install `graphlab` to correct if you have done any mistake : [Link](https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html)

Comment: this solved a similar issue I had while installing textblob. It was conflicting with matplotlib-base

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems with: 
conda install -y -c bioconda cwltool

I solved it by : 
conda config --add channels conda-forge

the package (cwltool) I was trying to install could not solve dependencies that where satisfied in a different channel